# if (other.gameObject.Find("GoRoomNext"))

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я программирую на c#, в Unity. У меня есть такие строки:

```
        if (other.gameObject.Find("GoRoomNext"))
        {

        }
```

Выходит ошибка: Member
`'GameObject.Find(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`. Как её исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка сообщает вам, что этот метод нельзя вызывать от экземпляра класса, его нужно вызывать от самого класса, то есть так:

```
        if (GameObject.Find("GoRoomNext"))
        {

        }
```